# Access data across R and Scala scripts

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

Is there a way to share data across R and Scala scripts assuming both scripts run against the same Spark cluster?  For example, I want to pull data from a source system using Scala, and I want to access this data in R without having to persist it.

I've tried using registerTempTable to save the data in memory but I cant seem to access it in another script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this (between any sessions). You should write data to disk. (hdfs, etc.)